# CreateStackNavigator in react native returning null

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm new to react-native and I'm trying to implement `react-stack-navigator` but the function `createStackNavigator` is returning null. I've been following a tutorial that didn't have this issue with the same code, any ideas would be appreciated .. here is my error:

[image: error screen]

here is my code:

```
import { createStackNavigator } from "react-navigation-stack";
import { createAppContainer } from "react-navigation";
import { Home } from "../components/Home";
import { Test } from "../components/Test";

const screens = {
  home: {
    screen: Home
  },

  test: {
    screen: Test
  }
};

const HomeStack = createStackNavigator(screens);

export default createAppContainer(HomeStack);
```

here is my App.js file :

```
/**
 * Sample React Native App
 * https://github.com/facebook/react-native
 *
 * @format
 * @flow
 */

import React, { Component } from "react";
import {
  StyleSheet,
  ScrollView,
  View,
  Text,
  StatusBar,
  Button
} from "react-native";

import Navigator from "./routes/homeStack";

export class App extends Component {
  constructor() {}

  render() {
    return <Navigator />;
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({});
```

here is home component:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {
  StyleSheet,
  ScrollView,
  View,
  Text,
  StatusBar,
  Button
} from "react-native";
import { About } from "./About";
import { Contact } from "./Contact";

export class Home extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <View>
          <Text>This is Home Component</Text>
        </View>
        <Button
          title="navigate to Test"
          onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate("test")}
        ></Button>
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

here is test component:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {
  StyleSheet,
  ScrollView,
  View,
  Text,
  StatusBar,
  Button
} from "react-native";

export class Test extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      something: "This is Test Component"
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <View>
          <Text>this.state.something</Text>
        </View>
        <Button
          title="navigate to Home"
          onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate("home")}
        ></Button>
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

here is code for package.json:

```
{
  "name": "reviewsApp2",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint ."
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.5",
    "react": "16.9.0",
    "react-native": "0.61.5",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.5.3",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^1.4.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^0.6.2",
    "react-native-screens": "^2.0.0-alpha.23",
    "react-navigation": "^4.0.10",
    "react-navigation-stack": "^2.0.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.6.2",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.6.2",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^0.0.5",
    "babel-jest": "^24.9.0",
    "eslint": "^6.5.1",
    "jest": "^24.9.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.56.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.9.0"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

Comment: Are `Home` & `Test` properly exported?  i.e. are you doing `export default Home` or `export Home`?

Comment: yes they are exported 
export class Test extends Component{...}
export class Home extends Component {...}

Comment: can you share your code for Home and Test?

Comment: Okay cool and you are saying that `HomeStack` is undefined?

Comment: yes HomeStack is undefined

Comment: shared code for Home and Test components

Comment: @wissam123123 just to cover all basis, did you install the npm package?

Comment: @Johan yes.. i shared the package.json file if its of any help

Comment: This works for me: https://snack.expo.io/r1wVXFheI (I copied your code).  The only diff for me was that I added a default export for the app.js

Comment: I also commented out the `About`/`Contact` components in `Home`, as I don't have those components, but assuming you do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A fresh pair of eyes always makes a difference (Welcome to React-Native and dev in general).

You are importing two components in the `Home`, namely `About` and `Contact`, i.e.

```
import { About } from "./About";
import { Contact } from "./Contact"
```

Based on the context we have, these don't exist.  Either removing these imports or commenting them out should resolve your error.

Annoyingly, React-Native doesn't always present the best error message, but it's actively being worked on.  i.e. I sometimes get different error messages when I have a debugger attached vs not attached (worth messing around with this).

The other change, was changing the type export of your `App` file, i.e.

`export default App`

It'll be very beneficial to grasp the concept of the two different types of export/imports (namely default exports/imports vs named exports/imports).

See working example: https://snack.expo.io/r1wVXFheI